# FullCalendar get clicked date on multi-day event

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar, momentjs

I want to use [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) to build a system where parents can book holiday-care for their parents. So I need to add the holidays as events to make the user clear when they can book. My problem is: I need the exact day on which the user has clicked. Lets say we've test holidays from 1st to 20th of august and the user want to book the 15th of August, I need to get the 15th of August.

This seems not to work with FullCalendar in this combination. The `dayClick` Event is exactly what I need:

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view, resourceObj) {
    alert('You clicked on ' + moment(date).format('L'));
}
```

BUT it only works when no event was specified on the clicked date. But in my case I have a event. So `eventClick` gets fired instead of `dayClick`. `eventClick` has the disadvantage that I only get the whole event (like *test holidays* from 1st fo 20th of August in my example), but NOT the day where the user clicked on.

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    // No 'date' parameter avaliable here, only calEvent.start and  calEvent.end for the WHOLE event
    // But not the date where the user clicked on
    alert("Event started: " + moment(calEvent.start).format('L'));
}
```

To make it more clear, a full demo-case in this scenario:

```
$('#test-div').fullcalendar({
    events: [{
        title: 'Test holidays',
        start: '2016-08-01',
        end: '2016-08-20'
    }]
});
```

Now we've the test holidays registered as event from 2016-08-01 to 2016-08-20. I need a solution that when the user clicks on 2016-08-02 I get 2016-08-02. On 2016-08-05 I get 2016-08-05 and so on. The `eventClick` event would only gave me 2016-08-01 as start and 2016-08-20 as end.

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="text id="plannedTaskDateTime">
```

add to the above input type

```
<script>

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            events: [{
    title: 'Test holidays',
    start: '2016-08-01',
    end: '2016-08-20'
}],
            editable: true,
            defaultView: defaultViewtype,
            firstDay: weekStartDay,//Start day of Calender
            hiddenDays: weekEndArr, // Hide Days Non Working Days 
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            eventRender: function(event, element) {
                 if(event.icon){          
                    element.find(".fc-title").prepend("<i class='fa fa-"+event.icon+"'></i>");
                 }
            },

            dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view,start, end, allDay) {
                var cellYear = date.year();
                var cellMonth = date.month() + 1;
                var cellDay = date.date();
                $('#plannedTaskDateTime').val(cellYear+"-"+cellMonth+"-"+cellDay+" 00:00:00");

                var check = generateDateTOYYMMDD(date._d)
                var today = generateDateTOYYMMDD(new Date())
                if(check < today)
                {
                        alert('You can not plan for past');
                }
                 else
                {
                   //DO as You wish
                }



            }

        });

function generateDateTOYYMMDD(DateObj){
    var DateDay = DateObj.getDate();
    DateDay = (DateDay<10) ? "0"+DateDay : DateDay;
    var DateMonth = DateObj.getMonth() + 1;
    DateMonth = (DateMonth<10) ? "0"+DateMonth : DateMonth;
    var DateYear = DateObj.getFullYear();
    var DateStr = DateYear + "-" + DateMonth+ "-" + DateDay;
    return DateStr;
}
</script>
```

Comment: The problem with our solution is that it will only catch clicks in the box of the day, which are NOT on the (Holiday) event bar. See http://www.image-hoster.de/files/471f13497c7a957113f897e4b.png I mean clicks in the red box, which I expect many users will do because it's intuitive. When you click in the red box, nothing happens. Only outside of the box.